# TinyMCE 4.X: add Alignment Options to Context Menu

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I try to create a custom Context Menu in TinyMCE.

```
contextmenu:"cut copy paste | alignment"
```

and the "alignment" be like

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('context_menu',function(editor) {
    editor.addMenuItem('alignment', {
        text: 'Alignment',
        menu:[{text: 'Left', icon: 'alignleft', cmd: 'alignleft'},
            {text: 'Center', icon: 'aligncenter', cmd: 'aligncenter'},
            {text: 'Right', icon: 'alignright', cmd: 'alignright'},
            {text: 'Justify', icon: 'alignjustify', cmd: 'alignjustify'}],
        context:'alignment'
    });
});
```

The code give the context menu with align options but when i click on align left/right/justify nothing seems working.The text is not aligning as per the command. I tried "cmd" and "format" options but nothing seems working.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer from TinyMCE documentation. Here we go, we just have to fire an onclick event with editor execCommand instead of cmd and the commands will be

**JustifyLeft, JustifyCenter, JustifyRight, JustifyFull**

```
onclick: function () {
                editor.execCommand('JustifyLeft');
            }
```